# Flag subdirectories that are missing a particular file

Tags: python

In the directory structure:

```
"~/clients/images/"
```

where `clients` contains almost 1000 `images` subdirectories, I need to discover which of these subdirectories are missing the file `master.jpg`. I've tried unsuccessfully to print the desired output to the console, and I have tried writing it to a .txt file.

```
import os

path = os.path.expanduser('~/clients/images/')
mast  = '/master.jpg'

print '\nFinding missing masters...n'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        recipe = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if "master.jpg" not in filenames:
            print str(dirnames), '\n'
```

What this currently does is to seemingly print a ton of empty lists ("[]") and newlines, which is definitely not what I want (all I want to know is **which subdirectories are missing 'master.jpg'**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
  if "master.jpg" not in filenames:  print dirpath
```

For each 3-element object generated by the `os.walk` generator, the first element (`dirpath` in your code) represents the directory being examined.  The third element (`filenames` in your code) is a list containing all files found in that directory, so checking for the absence of `master.jpg` in `filenames` is the right thing to do.

I'm assuming that `master.jpg` will always be a file - if there is the possibility that there could be a subdirectory named `master.jpg` (seems odd, but the requirements are yours and not mine), then you might have to do:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
  if "master.jpg" not in filenames and "master.jpg" not in dirnames:  print dirpath
```